# How to replace all strings to numbers contained in each string in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to find all values with following pattern :

```
value="4"
value="403"
value="200"
value="201"
value="116"
value="15"
```

and replace it with value inside scopes.

I'm using the following regex to find the pattern :

```
.*"\d+"
```

How can I do a replacement?

Comment: What is the replacement part? Could you give an example?

Comment: ^.*value="([^"]*)".*$ check this regex and repace the value \1 where the value needed

Answer (score 203, accepted):

In Notepad++ to replace, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace menu.

Then if you check the "Regular expression" button and you want in your replacement to use a part of your matching pattern, you must use "capture groups" (read more on [google](https://www.google.gr/search?q=regular+expressions+capture+groups)). For example, let's say that you want to match each of the following lines

```
value="4"
value="403"
value="200"
value="201"
value="116"
value="15"
```

using the `.*"\d+"` pattern and want to keep only the number. You can then use a capture group in your matching pattern, using parentheses `(` and `)`, like that: `.*"(\d+)"`. So now in your replacement you can simply write `$1`, where $1 references to the value of the 1st capturing group and will return the number for each successful match. If you had two capture groups, for example `(.*)="(\d+)"`, `$1` will return the string `value` and `$2` will return the number.

So by using:

Find: `.*"(\d+)"`

Replace: `$1`

It will return you

```
4
403
200
201
116
15
```

Please note that there many alternate and better ways of matching the aforementioned pattern. For example the pattern `value="([0-9]+)"` would be better, since it is more specific and you will be sure that it will match only these lines. It's even possible of making the replacement without the use of capture groups, but this is a slightly more advanced topic, so I'll leave it for now :)

Comment: For the replace, `$1` didn't work for me.  I used `\1` instead and that worked.

Comment: `\1` Works in all versions of Notepad++.  `$1` only works in the newer ones.

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't work with the `Hex Editor` plugin. In hex view mode Notepad++ doesn't show the `Regular Expression` option for Search/Replace. In text view mode I do see the `Regular Expression` option for Search/Replace. I'm using Notepad++ Version 6.9.2, which is the current version at this time.

Answer (score 16):

psxls gave a great answer but I think my Notepad++ version is slightly different so the $ (dollar sign) capturing did not work.

I have **Notepad++ v.5.9.3** and here's how you can accomplish your task:

Search for the pattern: **value=\"([0-9]*)\"**
And replace with: **\1** (whatever you want to do around that capturing group)

Ex. Surround with square brackets

[\1] --> *will produce value="[4]"*

Comment: `\1` Helped me to keep the number but remove the quote behind it. I had arround 7400 lines in a document like `tablename.columnname = '12345'`. The first quote was easy to remove, the second was done using your `\1` in the replace textbox. Thanks, +1

Answer (score 8):

Replace `(.*")\d+(")`

With `$1x$2`

Where `x` is your "value inside scopes".

Answer (score 0):

I have **Notepad++ v6.8.8**

**Find**: [([a-zA-Z])]

**Replace**: [\'\1\']

Will produce:
$array[XYZ] => $array['XYZ']

Answer (score -2):

**Find:** `value="([\d]+|[\d])"`

**Replace:** `\1`

It will really return you

`4`
`403`
`200`
`201`
`116`
`15`

**js:**

```
a='value="4"\nvalue="403"\nvalue="200"\nvalue="201"\nvalue="116"\nvalue="15"';
a = a.replace(/value="([\d]+|[\d])"/g, '$1');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: How does this JavaScript solution relate to the question which was tagged with Notepad++?

Comment: How does faulty, broken responses 1 and 2 may relate  to the question which was tagged with Notepad++?

Comment: Why I asked the question here? Because I can not create questions. Because I  have not enough reputation score.

Comment: There is no such reputation requirement for asking questions as you claim - you *could not* possibly have been restricted. Try again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: The question was asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112018/find-multiple-words-in-one-line-using-notepad But limited in words to search for. Limitation is!

Comment: You can not - IIS, notepade++, Multiple and all over global words. Nobody finds. Yet. But there are links - http://wefixbugs.com/blog.php?askid=50119#.U5mQC_l_tv8