# Notepad++ truncate LatLng data

Tags: regex, notepad++, kml

I have a KML file that has multiple coordinates. I want to trim the coordinates to see if it will reduce the size.

*CHANGES*
The LatLng is different and not in a consistent format. Below is a sample of the LatLng that I have within my file. My apologies for not using a more accurate capture I didn't realize that it would affect the RegEx.

```
20.0649556884364,42.546758117893,0
-6.665609089909049,61.4394550582227,0
142.843146200241,54.2804088338613,0
```

This goes on for awhile as it is a multigeometry polygon. I would like to reduce the LatLng to `20.1234,20.1234`

How do I remove the last 9 digits leaving only 4 after the period?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad does that help a bit? you just need to tailor the regex to your need and fiddle with the return variables \1 and such

Comment: I'm working with this one but even the updated one does not work for notepad++ 6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find what:

```
(\.\d{4})\d+
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iR4zQ1/1)

Comment: Sorry it's still not working I do the following 'ctrl+H' selected

Comment: did you enable the `regular expression` radio button?

Comment: I selected that and also .matches newline then in the find I typed the code you provided and the replace with a $1.

Comment: Sorry this works, I failed to mention that the code is a bit different than my example. I made the edit to my original post to reflect the accurate LatLng

Comment: In Notepad++, you can use both `\1` and `$1` in the replacement string.

Comment: @JeremyA1 did you want to remove 0 space present next to comma? try to provide the exact inut at very first.. see https://regex101.com/r/iR4zQ1/2

Comment: @JeremyA1: I thought you were looking for `\b(\d+\.\d{4})[\d,]+(?:\s|$)` to replace with `$1,`...