# How to replace a substring of a regular expression in text editor

Tags: regex, string, replace, notepad++, text-editor

This is my sample string:

```
(20,'7,8,9|1|X',1,1,1,1,1),
(81,'3',1,1,1,1,10),          
(83,'3',1,1,1,1,15),
```

My task is to replace "|X'" with "|X|X|X" ONLY where line starts with "(20,"

Using www.rubular.com I already got the reg ex. : ^(20,'.*)X' 
that matches this string: (20,'7,8,9|1|X'   That means, replace command would replace whole strings matching my reg. Ex.

I can't figure out how to select just that substring "|X'" and replace only that.

Preferably, i'd like to use Notepad++ , if it is capable to replace reg-ex substrings.

Comment: Try replacing `^(\(20,.*?\d)\|X'` with `$1|X|X|X'`. If there are already replaced `|X`s, this won't replace them.

Comment: @stribizhev  Thanx ! That works perfectly...

Comment: Shall I post it? If you choose any answer below, I won't.

Comment: I think you can give it as an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the following into the Notepad++ Find/Replace window under "Find":

```
^(\(20,.*)(\|X)(.*\),)$
```

There are three *capturing* groups in the above regex.  The first group `(\(20,.*)` matches everything before the `|X`, the second group `(\|X)` is what you are trying to find, and the third group `(.*\),)` is everything coming after the `|X`.  The matches themselves are available as the variables `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`, corresponding to the first, second, and third group match from left to right.

Type the following into the "Replace" box:

```
$1\|X\|X\|X$3
```

This effectively replaces only what you want while preserving the rest of the line.

Here is a link where you can test the regex:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/dY8sD7/1)

And [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad) to the canonical Stack Overflow article discussing find/replace in Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

You may replace using the following regex:

```
^(\(20,.*?\d)\|X'
```

And replace with `$1|X|X|X'`

If there are already replaced `|X`s, this won't replace them.

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of line
- `(\(20,.*?\d)` - a group of....

  - `\(20,` - literal `(20,`
  - `.*?` - 0 or more characters other than a newline (as few as possible, `*?` is a lazy quantifier)
  - `\d` - a digit
- `\|X'` - a literal `|X'`

Here is a screen with Notepad++ settings:

[image]

In the replacements string, we use *back-references* like `$&`, `$1`, etc. (not variables) and the pattern inside `(...)` is called a *capturing group* (not a match, a *match* is the whole text matched by the entire expression). More details can be found at [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression use groups to capture substring and, generally, editors/programmation langage use the syntax `$n` to use those groups. It means you can use this and replace with this : `$1|X|X|X`

Answer (score -1):

```
re.sub(r"^(\(20,.*?)\|X(\'.*)$", r"\1|X|X|X\2", "(20,'7,8,9|1|X',1,1,1,1,1)")
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. This is especially true of regexen, which are notorious for being opaque line noise to most.