# Notepad ++ search for multiple number strings in large file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large log file with thousands of lines: (example)

```
3125 = adugbo1root1.gr-u.it_1449288148_C1_HDR
3126 = adugbo1dir1.direzione.gr-u.it_1449288167_C1_HDR
3128 = adugbovdir2.direzione.gr-u.it_1449288072_C1_F3
3129 = adugbovaage1.aurage.lan_1449288143_C1_F1
3130 = adubbovugfb01.ugfbanca.lan_1449288049_C1_F3
3132 = adugbo1sfinge.aurora.lan_1449288054_C1_F3
3133 = adugbo1root1.gr-u.it_1449288149_C1_F1
3134 = adugbovaage1.aurage.lan_1449288144_C1_F1
3135 = adugbo1root1.gr-u.it_1449288148_C1_F1
3136 = adugbo1root1.gr-u.it_1449288147_C1_F1
3137 = adugbo1dir1.direzione.gr-u.it_1449288167_C1_F1
3138 = adugbo1dir1.direzione.gr-u.it_1449288169_C1_HDR
3139 = adugbo1dir1.direzione.gr-u.it_1449288168_C1_HDR
3140 = adugbovroot2.gr-u.it_1449288069_C1_F3
```

I have a smaller list of numbers that i need to pull the lines from this log file.

i.e.

> 3130 = adubbovugfb01.ugfbanca.lan_1449288049_C1_F3
>
> 3138 = adugbo1dir1.direzione.gr-u.it_1449288169_C1_HDR

I can run a regex search for (3130)|(3138)|....

However this is not searching for a "match whole word only".

I.e. the same search will pull out:

> 23130 = pegasoweb.servizi.gr-u.it_1449948649_C1_F60
>
> 43138 = apunbovazoto.servizi.gr-u.it_1450647109_C1_F57

How can i run a regex search for only the string in the bracket?

Comment: Like `\b(3130|3138)\b`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Find/Replace in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepend your regular expression with a `^` to indicate the start of the line.  Add `\s` at the end to match the whitespace.

Comment: Thanks, (^3130)|(^3138) does exactly what i need.