# How can i delete N characters (including spaces and alphanum ) after a given string in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a txt file that looks like :

aaa  1122 bbb ccccccccccc ddddd

eee  1254 fff eeeeeeeeeee ggggg END OF BLOCK     1

zzz  1296 jjj rrrrrrrrrrr ttttt

sss  2548 iii mmmmmmm vvvvv END OF BLOCK     2

```
                            END OF BLOCK  1000
```

And i want to delete all the occurences of "END OF BLOCK   N"

.
.

Comment: You are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad

Answer (score 0):

Providing all of the "END BLOCK N" instances are at the end of lines you can do "Replace All" with this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, but i'm wondering if the END OF BLOCK.....N wasn't at the end of the ligne , and suppose that this string contains spaces.   
eg:  xxxxxxxxxxxxx END OF BLOCK    1  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa END OF BLOCK    2 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  END OF BLOCK 1000

Comment: Then change the "find what : " to END OF BLOCK \d+