# Edit date in Notepad++ using regex

Tags: notepad++

I have dates in the following format dd-mm-yyyy. And I have a document which has all 365 dates. How can I replace every date within quotes. ie. 'dd-mm-yyyy' in Notepad++ using regex?

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad it helped me!

Comment: You could use `\b\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b` as a searchpattern and `'$0'` for replace. However this is not failsafe, you would also quote e.g. 99-99-999 - not sure if you have to worry about that. It will also quote already quoted dates again.

Comment: @hollie3406  : Thanks... Got it :)

Comment: @SebastianProske:Cheers!. It helped. Good day.