# How can I replace a word from a line counting from the last in Notepad++ regular expression?

Tags: regex, notepad++, digit

This is my file:

```
1912-ssc-math-2-1-সেট
1782-ssc-math-3-1-বর্গ-সংবলিত-সূত্রাবলি-ও-প্রয়োগ
1815-ssc-math-3-3-উৎপাদকে-বিশ্লেষণ
1783-ssc-math-3-4-ভাগশেষ-উপপাদ্য
1722-ssc-math-4-1-সূচক
1749-ssc-math-4-2-লগারিদম
1889-ssc-math-5-1-চলক,-সমীকরণ-ও-অভেদ
1942-ssc-math-5-2-এক-চলকবিশিষ্ট-দ্বিঘাত-সমীকরণ-ও-এর-ব্যবহার
1890-ssc-math-6-রেখা,-কোণ-ও-ত্রিভুজ
```

Now, I want to delete all content after last digit(number). Means, I want to delete:

```
-সেট
-বর্গ-সংবলিত-সূত্রাবলি-ও-প্রয়োগ
-উৎপাদকে-বিশ্লেষণ
...
```

How can I delete this unicode? Or how can I select the last number so that I can delete all content after the last number(digit) in **Notepad++**?

Comment: try **[this](https://regex101.com/r/dA7sR9/2)**..replace with `$1`

Comment: You may use `(\d)[^\d\r\n]+$` and replace with `$1`

Comment: Best is `([0-9])[^0-9\r\n]+$` since `\d` in Notepad++ Boost regex also matches non-ASCII digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Find/Replace in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\D+$`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: It will remove more text if there are other lines between these lines that do not start with a digit. Also, `\d` and `\D` is Unicode aware in Notepad++.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You're right but it is not said in OP. This is working for the sample text given