# Removing a specific section of a list in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a list with the following format:

```
companyname,companyaddress,companytelephone
```

It's 500k lines of code, with the same structure.

I'd like the final result to be just

```
companyaddress,companytelephone
```

(deleting the 'companyname,'). How can I do so?

Comment: The section where your list is presumably supposed to be is actually blank. It won't be possible for anyone to help you without that.

Comment: @computerfreaker Someone edited the question and removed the important part. I've reverted the edit.

Comment: @melpomene Odd, I checked revision history for exactly that before commenting. Must have been an oversight on my part. Thanks for the rollback.

Comment: can someone help me?pls

Comment: @AlissaWundsson I don't see what your question has to do with programming (it sounds more like "how do I use my text editor?"), so I've voted to close it as off-topic.

Comment: then apply the same critera to all members, and not just for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad

Comment: @AlissaWundsson That question has a bit of regex code in there, at least. Have you even tried anything?

Comment: I have, and as a last resource (as i always do) I ask here

Comment: @AlissaWundsson So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

(snip)… Your answer is to use the regular expression option in the search and replace. I assumed that you have some structured data, i.e, `<name> delimiter1 <address> delimiter2 <phone>`, and delimiter1 is a tab, then:

```
search for: `^[^\t]+?\t`
replace with: [leave empty]
```

\t  … is the substitute for a tab

***Given your edit***  with comma-space as delimiter1, it will be difficult to accomplish a solution in one go because you will need to be aware of company names that include commas. For example, any ending with Inc., LLC, LLP or partnerships, such as "Curly, Larry & Moe, LLP." Therefore, I think I would do multiple search-replaces, visually checking the data between each.

```
(1) Find from start of line <name> delimiter1 <number>: ^(.+?), (\d)
Replace with # <name> tab <number>: #$1\t$2
```

See if there are any records different from the replace pattern in (1). If a few, edit by hand replacing those comma-space with tabs. If many, you will have to do more search-and-replaces. When you have no outliers, do:

```
(last) Find from start of line through to the first tab: ^[^\t]\t
Replace with nothing: [leave empty]
```

If your delimiter1 is not comma-space but quote-comma-space-quote, then instead regex search: `^.+?", "` and replace with nothing. Done!

**Alternate solution for non-delimiter records:**

If the data is character length dependent, i.e., `<name> spaces to the 30th character <address> spaces to the 100th character <phone>`, then:

```
search for: `^(.){30}`
replace with: [leave empty]
```

Try on a sample copy first. Good luck.