# Notepad++: add parentheses to timestamps

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have text with timestamps for gaps in audio, e.g. "We met 51:33 at the bar". I need to add paretheses to timestamps to make them more readable: "We met (51:33) at the bar". How do I do that in Notepad++??

I already created a regex search and replace. It searches for \d\d:\d\d and replaces it with (\d\d:\d\d). Unfortunately, I get (dd:dd) everywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Find/Replace in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad)

Comment: @HassanAhmed: No, definitely not the duplicate of that question.

Comment: @HassanAhmed: my question is very specific and I got a dovetailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may enhance the regex a bit with lookarounds `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` to make sure you get `xx:xx` not enclosed with other digits, and use *backreference* to the whole match (`$&`) in the replacement:

*Search*: `(?<!\d)\d\d:\d\d(?!\d)`
*Replace*: `\($&\)`

Note: the `(` and `)` must be escaped in the replacement pattern since NPP uses Boost conditional replacement pattern syntax.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I won't even try to understand the wizardry you've created, but it works perfectly!

Comment: I think I explained the purpose of the lookarounds and the backreference. You can check what they do at http://regular-expressions.info.

Comment: I know you did, it's just that it's digging into it is not justified right now.