# Replace a different and many characters or word's to single word in multiple Java files in different scenarios

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, notepad++

Need to replace 2000 different words into single word i.e "ex". in java files.
For Example:

```
catch (Any_Exception qq) {
logger.error("error message", qq);
}
```

above scenario should be as below :

```
catch (Any_Exception ex) {
logger.error("error message", ex)
}
```

like 'qq' there are multiple different words are present, so instead of Brute Force. Is there any way to replace all those 2000 different and multiple words into single word or character. 
The solutions which i find here are for specific characters to replace. Can any one help me in this. THANK YOU.

Comment: What tool are you using? The simple regex `, ex)` catches the "ex" you want.

Comment: Hi Maroun, i am not using any tool for this. Just tried in Notepad++ and trying to write script but i am not getting.

Comment: If you are using Notepad++ you can try [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

Does the following regex solve your problem?

```
(logger.error\(")(.+)(",)(.+)(\);)
```

Replace it with:

```
\1\2\3ex\5
```

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/VeD5ds/2).