# Regex: Match the word between tags

Tags: regex, windows, notepad

I have this almost 5000 html files with this meta tag, but with different content:

```
<meta name="Abstract" content="I must &#226;follow the path."/>
```

I want to match only the `&#226;`, from this particular tag. I made a regex, but doesn't work:

```
(?s)<meta name="Abstract" content=(&#226;)(.*\"/>)
```

Basically, `&#226;` means `â` in ANSI characters. I made a mistake and I got this into this meta tag. So, I need to replace all `&#226;` with simple `a`, but only in this particular meta tab, not in whole files.

Comment: You are going to change 5000 files with notepad.exe?

Comment: Please add more information regarding your objective and the tools you will be using.

Comment: I test in notepad++, and I edit almost 20.000 with GrepWin or TextCrawler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Notepad++:

Find:

```
(<meta name="Abstract" content=".*)&#226;(.*"\/>)
```

Replace:

```
\1a\2
```

\1 and \2 refer to the capture groups. For more information, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/how-to-replace-all-strings-to-numbers-contained-in-each-string-in-notepad).

Comment: That is dangerous, because if there isn't a match in the current tag, the regex will match anyway, but straddle the replacement into the next tag with a match.

Comment: no Benjamin, this will match the entire meta tag, and not only `<meta name="Abstract"` . Besides, I need to match and replace `&#226;` with `a`

Comment: @JustMe Modified my answer to adjust to your needs.