# How to extract the Url from data in XML format with Notepad++?

Tags: regex, xml

I've got a list of several hundreds sites in the config.xml file. I need to extract all url sites without port 80 according these listed below binding tags. Is there any the most exact regex syntax which will allow to create a such list? I am using Notepad++ to do the editing.

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="217.145.55.21:80:rwasianew.inforce.dk" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="217.145.55.86:80:rwasianew.inforce.dk" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:rwasianew-cn.inforce.dk" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:rwasianew-th.inforce.dk" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="217.145.55.86:80:rwasianew-splash.inforce.dk" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:rwbuilddeskgb.synkronvia.com" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:rwbuilddeskdk.synkronvia.com" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:rwbuilddesknl.synkronvia.com" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:rwbuilddeskde.synkronvia.com" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:rwbuilddeskint.synkronvia.com" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:rwbuilddeskpl.synkronvia.com" />
```

Comment: Can you add example of desired output?

Comment: C#, IIS, Win10. but I need only a plain list with urls. I'm using just a notepad ++ with a regular expression search feature.

Comment: Output: rwbuilddeskint.synkronvia.com, rwbuilddesknl.synkronvia.com, rwasianew-cn.inforce.dk etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all strings to numbers contained in each string in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/how-to-replace-all-strings-to-numbers-contained-in-each-string-in-notepad)

Comment: Instead of answering in the comment you should probably update/edit your question.

Comment: Your example is missing an enclosing tag to be valid XML.

Answer (score 2):

Not a regular expression but an [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/plain"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="//binding">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(@bindingInformation, ':'), ':')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
rwasianew.inforce.dk
rwasianew.inforce.dk
rwasianew-cn.inforce.dk
rwasianew-th.inforce.dk
rwasianew-splash.inforce.dk
rwbuilddeskgb.synkronvia.com
rwbuilddeskdk.synkronvia.com
rwbuilddesknl.synkronvia.com
rwbuilddeskde.synkronvia.com
rwbuilddeskint.synkronvia.com
rwbuilddeskpl.synkronvia.com
```

There are multiple online services available for example [this](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=65728209-372a-4a0d-8f54-7a5d27bf3b68-xsltransformation) one.

Comment: That's it !! Thank you Micha :)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Search Mode: `Regular expression`

Find: `<binding protocol=".*" bindingInformation=".*:80:(.*)" \/>`

Replace: `\1`